# how to replace certain images (by name) to respective text in word by vba

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

i need to replace images in my word document by text like:
  graphic1 -> text1
  graphic2 -> text2
  etc

Any ideas? is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro (find image, insert text, delete image)?

Comment: Sure, but this way it finds all graphic, not the specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far best way was to go and find distictive properties of images (like height and width) and replace them as below:

```
Dim myShape As InlineShape


For Each myShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  myShape.Select
  ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range

  Select Case myShape.Width
  Case "13,5"

    Selection.Delete
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" g1"
  Case "8"

    Selection.Delete
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" g2"
  Case "19,5"

    Selection.Delete
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" g3"
  End Select

Next myShape
```